# ajax Autocomplete Extender is not Working When using PageRouting in asp.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, url-routing, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using autocomplete extender for getting suggestions in .aspx page it was working fine and when i have routed the URL it was not working properly and some times it's not responding.

In the routed url all html content is displaying letter by letter Suggestions what iam getting in routed URL
[Click here Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyBSs.png)

index.aspx page this is the page where i have written the autocomplete extender.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   </head>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <form runat="server" class="body" id="form">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <div class="head">
           <div class="background"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " style="padding:0%; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" style="padding:0px; font-size:8px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_keyword_search" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="search" Style="height:50px; border: 1px solid #55CBFF;" placeholder="Skills" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender CompletionListItemCssClass="aut" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="high"  FirstRowSelected="true" TargetControlID="txt_keyword_search" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="20" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="SearchSkills" ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

                        </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0px;">
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_locations" class="form-control" DataTextFormatString=""  Style="height:50px; border: 1px solid #55CBFF;" runat="server">
                                 </asp:DropDownList>

                        </div>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" class="input-group-addon" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" ValidationGroup="search" style="background-color:#55cbff; padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; border: 1px solid #55CBFF;" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="color:#fff;"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.aspx.cs this is the page where i have written the webmethod for autocomplete extender

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public static List<string> SearchSkills(string prefixText)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constrng"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "select top 5 id, name from master where name like @SeTextlp2 + '%' and isactive=1 order by name";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeTextlp2", prefixText);
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        List<string> list = new List<string>();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                list.Add(sdr["name"].ToString());
                            }

                        }
                        conn.Close();
                        return list;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Global.asax.cs  this how i have written the routed URL

```
 static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           // routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Ignore("css/{*relpath}");
            routes.Ignore("Images/{*relpath}");
            routes.Ignore("js/{*relpath}");
            routes.Ignore("fonts/{*relpath}");
            routes.Ignore("bin/{*relpath}");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Default", string.Empty, "~/index.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Route", "{*.}", "~/404.aspx", true);
        }
```

Web.config this is the configuration i have done for my project

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="30720" executionTimeout="3600"/>
      <pages validateRequest="false">
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="JobseekerWebapp.axpxauth" protection="All" loginUrl="/Login" defaultUrl="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="240000" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" cookieless="UseCookies" />

    </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Student"/>
        <deny roles="Recruiter"/>
      </authorization>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error-page.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=60;" />
  </appSettings>
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31457280" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here iam looking for the solution for this problem

Comment: I suggest checking the console in the Inspect Element when its not working. You might see some errors there.

Comment: Iam getting html code letter by letter as suggestions like shown in the above image